# Webdriver.io losing connection during execution

Tags: google-chrome, testing, webdriver-io, acceptance-testing

I have a `wdio` running tests in [headful] Chrome on Mac and it works fine.
Now I want to run same tests in Ubuntu Linux VM and I am facing strange issue:

Sometimes (often) test execution gets interrupted in the middle with following error, sometimes test just works.

Also I noticed that `browser.pause(1000);` helps improve percent of successful runs but it is not reliable (also fails often) and slow.

Error message:

```
ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
chrome
    at new RuntimeError (/mypath/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/ErrorHandler.js:144:12)
    at Request._callback (/mypath/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:327:43)
    at self.callback (/mypath/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Request.emit (domain.js:421:20)
    at Request.onRequestError (/mypath/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (domain.js:421:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:395:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444

    at new RuntimeError (/mypath/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/ErrorHandler.js:144:12)
    at Request._callback (/mypath/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:327:43)
    at self.callback (/mypath/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Request.emit (domain.js:421:20)
    at Request.onRequestError (/mypath/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (domain.js:421:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:395:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
```

I found many similar topics but there people cannot make it work at all, in my case it fails (now always) during execution, so I couldn't find much useful advice.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you launching your grid? Externally or within your test cases itself

Comment: There is no grid, just local code, wdio and (headful) Chrome.

Comment: Can you post on of the scripts of yours? Mostly interested in the launch and closure part and mid part in between

Comment: Also please post the machine config, RAM, CPU, how many test you execute in parallel? Please post the details for the VM and not your main machine

Comment: Any update on this?